# Eclipse crashes after JBoss tools installation

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

For my school project I have to develop a Java EE application for this I installed JBoss and I installed JBoss tools to Eclipse and after installation Eclipse started showing the message below.

```
---------------------------
Eclipse
---------------------------
Java was started but returned exit code=1
C:\Windows\system32\javaw.exe
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar D:\eclipse\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
-os win32
-ws win32
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher D:\eclipse\eclipse.exe
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library D:\eclipse\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.1.R36x_v20100810\eclipse_1309.dll
-startup D:\eclipse\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
-exitdata 1094_5c
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-vm C:\Windows\system32\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar D:\eclipse\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar 
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

I should say that I am not familiar the Java world and I even don't know what Java EE really means but Eclipse was working with the Android plugins before that.

Comment: What steps did you take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added these two lines as first line of eclipse.ini file and it is working now.

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin
```

But the strange thing, I had already added these lines before I installed the jBoss tools some how jBoss tools rewrite the ini file.

Comment: Same solution for jre7 as well ... removing the javaw.exe at the end of that path (i.e. it was originally C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe for me) is what seems to make it work.  Strange.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I just updated JBoss Tools to "3.3.0.v20120302-0331-H69-Beta1", and it crashed Eclipse (Indigo) several times.

Comment: As I said before, the jBoss Tools changes the Eclipse setting. I can only suggest to check the settings and change them to appropriate ones for you and your system.

Answer (score 0):

The jboss tool added the `-vm C:/java/jdk1.8.0_25/bin/javaw.exe` in the end of `eclipse.ini`, which is repeated twice. Delete it and save, your problem will be solved.